# Left margin word spacing & no: of characters per line limit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Kepler Eclipse on Ubuntu Linux for C++ programming.
I want to have the following criteria for the code. Can any one kindly let me know how do I set this criteria in Eclipse?

1) The no: of spaces on the left side margin should be 4 spaces. Is there any settings in eclipse which would help me to set this criteria so that when I add new code/edit existing code it automatically sets the 4 spaces left margin limit.

2) No: of characters per line to be set to 80. Any new additions should automatically put the code in next line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to `Window` -> `preferences`. In the preferences dialog, go to `C++` then `Code Style`.

Here you can define how the code should look. Click `Edit` to start configuring. The settings you are talking about are found under `Line Wrapping`, Maximum Line width. This usually is set at 80 by default.

Unsure what you mean with item 1), I guess it's the tab indentation you are referring to. If so, look under `Indentation`.

Note that these settings can be shared, so if someone else has set up their environment you can choose to import their settings.

Comment: "Window -> preferences->C/C++->COde Style->Formatter Edit->Line Wrapping" option had options like "Max Line Width" to set the line width limit. But while editing the code in eclipse, I see that eclipse still allows the code to croass the limit I set in this filed. WHy is it so? Is there a way like as soon as the code in each line crosses the limit set in this field it should go to next line. 

Also the left margin white spaces also doens't seem to work. 

Is there anything that I'm missing here.

Comment: The code isn't formatted automatically. You can select parts of the code, like a method, and right click -> source -> format (ctrl + shitf + f)

Comment: Excellent. It worked for the left margin formatting. THanks :)
But I had a put a line width limit like 80 characters and even after I do right click->source->format, there are many lines which have width mmore than 80 characters.

Comment: @codeLover In the line wrapping part in preferences, you can see how the policy is applied for all parts of the code at the bottom. Sometimes a line wrap may make the code harder to read. Make sure none are set to "do not wrap". For me, "member access" was set to not wrap.